# Erlang nif does not upgrades

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I write a `nif` library in erlang. Also i write `load`, `upgrade` and `unload` functions.

This is my code:

```
#include "erl_nif.h"


int checksum(char *s)
{
    return 123;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


static ERL_NIF_TERM
checksum_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    return enif_make_int(env, checksum(""));
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


static int
load(ErlNifEnv* env, void** priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info)
{
    *priv_data = enif_open_resource_type(env,
                                         NULL,
                                         "cwm_utils_buf",
                                         NULL,
                                         ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE | ERL_NIF_RT_TAKEOVER,
                                         NULL);
    return 0;
}


static int
upgrade(ErlNifEnv* env, void** priv_data, void** old_priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info)
{
    *priv_data = enif_open_resource_type(env,
                                         NULL,
                                         "cwm_utils_buf",
                                         NULL,
                                         ERL_NIF_RT_TAKEOVER,
                                         NULL);
    return 0;
}


static void
unload(ErlNifEnv* env, void* priv_data)
{
    return ;
}


static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] = {
    {"checksum", 1, checksum_nif}
};



ERL_NIF_INIT(mynif, nif_funcs, &load, NULL, &upgrade, &unload);
```

In erlang shell i load this `nif` and run `checksum` function and it returns `123` and everything is fine!

After that i change return value of `checksum` to `123456` and compile and load the `nif` to erlang vm using `l(mynif)` command.

Here is the problem! If i run `checksum` function, the return value must be `123445` but it is still `123` and `nif` have not been upgraded.

What is the problem? I search a lot and tested some examples and libraries like `jiffy` but didn`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
code:purge(mynif).
code:delete(mynif).
l(mynif).
```

Comment: Can you better explain how and why this code snippet would be used to fix OP's problem?